# Network Applet has disapeared after an update to 15.04 (unity interface)

Tags: unity, network-manager, 15.04

I can't see if I'm logged on my wifi lan or internet lan since I update my ubuntu to 15.04 (I use Unity interface). I tried to update to kernel 4.0.3 but it changed nothing. The notification on the right up corner has disapeared

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are having a problem with /usr/bin/nm-applet part of the network-manager-gnome package. If so you can obtain that package for your architecture from [here.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/network-manager-gnome) Or better yet, remove and reinstall the package with the software center as shown below.

[image: nm-applet]

Don't let the name gnome in the package throw you. I am also using Unity and it's the stock network manager.